# Where function with numpy or xarray giving back the results including nan values

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

I have a big problem in computing a mask containing zeros and one's but preserving the nan-values.

Lets say I have a numpy-ndarray

```
ab = numpy.arange(0,10,0.5)
```

Now I emulate to have a nan-value: `ab[3]=0`. Now 'ab' looks like:

```
ab= array([ 0. ,  0.5,  1. ,  nan,  2. ,  2.5,  3. ,  3.5,  4. ,  4.5,  
    5.,5.5,  6. ,  6.5,  7. ,  7.5,  8. ,  8.5,  9. ,  9.5])
```

Now I want to mask all values below 5 to be '0' and all others to be '1' except for the nan-values, which should remain in the result.

I cannot do this with 'numpy.where' because it deletes the nan-values:

```
In [12]: numpy.where(a < 5, 1.0, 0.0)
/usr/bin/ipython3:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
#!/usr/bin/env python3
Out[12]: array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,
0.,  0., 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

What do I have to do to preserve the nan-values?

**Update:**
The solution with xarray is easy because the latest version supports a three-argument where-functionality. However, the NaN-Values remain in the result file.

Comment: xarray does support a 3 argument where now: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/latest/generated/xarray.where.html#xarray.where

Comment: Okay. Thats interesting to know. Up to now i only end up at the documenation page with xarray.where - function like this: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.where.html

Comment: Thanks, but I am not convinced that the NAN-Values are preserved during the xarray.where-Operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use another `np.where`

```
np.where(np.isnan(a), np.nan, numpy.where(a < 5, 1.0, 0.0))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have used an additional line to recover the nans: `afinal =numpy.where(a < 5, 1.0, 0.0); afinal[np.isnan(a)] = np.nan `. Do you have a feeling which of the solutions is faster? Your one-liner or my 2 commandos?

Comment: If you found the answer helpful, please upvate and mark at as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Like that:

```
import numpy as np

ab = np.arange(0,10,0.5)

ab[3] = np.nan

print(ab)

is_not_nan = np.logical_not(np.isnan(ab))
is_below_5 = ab < 5

is_not_nan_and_below_5 = np.logical_and(is_not_nan, is_below_5)

is_not_nan_and_not_below_5 = np.logical_and(is_not_nan, np.logical_not(is_below_5))

ab[is_not_nan_and_below_5] = 1.0
ab[is_not_nan_and_not_below_5] = 0.0

print(ab)
```